# When speaking of the item is going to be something in the future, is there other ways than "-to-be" suffix?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

For instance:

> I am your bride-to-be.

> He is your client-to-be.

Are there other ways to convey the meaning without making it a complicated sentence?

Thanks for any kind of resource/tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call them a "future [noun]": your future bride, your future client, etc.

For example, see the page in [Cambridge for future wife](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/example/english/future-wife).

Comment: Thanks. Is it always interchangeable for using `future *` and `*-to-be`?

Comment: They mean exactly the same, but 'future [noun]' is more generally used (I think people would say _future client_ rather than _client-to-be_).